# How to inject HTML to a Magento 1.4.0 plugin?

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

We're writing a Magento extension that injects HTML code into the store pages.
We're currently hooking on the `core_block_abstract_to_html_after` event to inject our HTML.

This event doesn't seem to be supported in Magento 1.4.0, only 1.4.1 and above.

What is the recommended method to inject HTML to all the store pages (but not to admin pages) in Magento 1.4.0?

Comment: To better answer to your question, what kind of html do you need to insert ? what are you trying to do ? Using core_block_abstract_to_html_after will insert HTML after every block rendered, are you sure you want to do that ?

Comment: @Bixi - I would like to insert a tag (HTML+javascript) one time in a page (e.g. Google Analytics tag). It's possible we're using the wrong event now - what is the correct API to use for this in 1.4.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to add Google Analytics code in your pages.

You don't need any code to do that as it's a standard magento functionnality.
Go to system / Configuration / Google Analytics. You just need to activate the functionnality and type your account ID

By the way if you really want to code something, you don't need an observer to do that (though, it's possible to do it with an observer). What you need to do is an XML layout update :

```
<reference name="before_body_end">
    <block type="module/block" template="module/template.phtml" name="my.block" />
</reference>
```

Your block will be automatically appended to the end of your BODY tag

Comment: I gave GA as an example ... my extension injects custom, proprietary HTML code, not actual GA.

Comment: Be clear from the start the next time. second part of my answer doesn't suit you ?

Comment: Please take a look at @Sveta's answer above (she has low reputation and thus can't comment here directly).

Comment: and why don't you inject you're block by appending it to layout element "content" or "header" or "head" or "footer" (which are text/list Blocks which automatically includes/display children without the need of any getChildHtml) ? That's a 99% chance of working to me as it's ROOT elements and can't be "commented" in templates.